# Generate Scripts for specific Data using Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to generate scripts but not for all tables ? I want to generate scripts in `D:\Folder\`.

Query

```
select * 
from DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
where model = 'animal_b'
```

Comment: Generate script for the table schema or data in the table?

Comment: You can use `Generate Scripts` option of the `SQL Server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have SQL Server Mangement Studio script only some of the records in a table, based on a filter. When scripting data, it's all or nothing.

What you can do, is copy the records into a new table, by doing something like this:

```
select * 
into DatabaseA.dbo.TableA_Copy
from DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
where model = 'animal_b'
```

And then simply script the data of TableA_Copy.

Comment: Glad to be of help. In case you don't have permissions to create a new table, either copy the data to a new table in a database where you have permission, or use the Import/Export-wizard as suggested elsewhere, to transfer the data to another server.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you want to get limited data basing on where condition from your table then execute select statement then

```
RIGHT CLICK >> COPY with Headers and paste into Excel Sheets 

>> Click on EXPORT IMPORT Wizard >>
>>Tick on Tab 
>>Tick on Text
```

you will get the same format as shown in Sql Editor

Comment: The original question is to generate scripts (ie a script of INSERT statements) not to extract the data.